# Broken photos on dslr

Tags: canon, dslr, troubleshooting, artifacts

During the last session with my Canon 50D, 4 or 5 photos from 180 appeared to be with artifacts:
[image: 1]
[Fullsize 15Mb](https://www.dropbox.com/s/wp028lqehrqjo8i/IMG_8300.JPG?dl=0)
[image: 3]
[Fullsize 7Mb](https://www.dropbox.com/s/u7480vxcq14ev9i/IMG_8323.JPG?dl=0)

These photos were already broken in preview on camera display, so it can't be usb cord issue.
Each jpg is broken the same way as corresponding raw.

How can I troubleshoot the reason?

Comment: Are the *full *RAW files damaged in the exact same way, or just their JPEG previews?

Comment: @mattdm, yes, seems like duplicate, thank you. And yes, full raws are damaged the same way, doublechecked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would start by using a different memory card.